# Integration DataStreamAPI and TableAPI

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-table-api

In addition to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61889706/how-to-check-datastream-in-flink-is-empty-or-having-data) I've create this example to integrate the `DataStreamAPI` and the `TableAPI` and this time I has no error, and I have two jobs instead of one, one is created for the `DataStreamAPI` which is running perfect, and the other job is created for the `TableAPI` which is running perfect too, but the only issue is that never receive any value from the `DataStreamAPI`, example:

```
        /*FILTERING NULL IDs*/
        final SingleOutputStreamOperator<Event> stream_filtered = eventsStream
                .filter(new NullidEventsFilterFunction())
                .uid("id_filter_operator")
                .name("Event Filter");

        final StreamTableEnvironment fsTableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(TableEnvironmentConfiguration.getEnv(), fsSettings);
        SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> toTable = stream_filtered.map(x -> x.id).name("Map for table");
        Table source = fsTableEnv.fromDataStream(toTable);
        source.execute(); /*without this line the TableAPI job is not started, but nothing happens if is not there either*/
        DataStream<String> finalRes = fsTableEnv.toAppendStream(source, String.class);
        finalRes.map((MapFunction<String, String>) value -> value)
                .name("Mapping after table")
                .addSink(new SinkFunction<String>() {
            @Override
            public void invoke(String value) {
                LOG.info("Record from table: " + value);
            }
        }).name("Sink after map from table");
        
        /*STARTING TRANSFORMATIONS*/
        Init.init(stream_filtered);
        env.execute(job_name);
```

by doing that I can see this line in the logger:

```
INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Source: Custom Source -> Event Mapper -> Watermarks Added -> Event Filter -> Map for table -> SourceConversion(table=[Unregistered_DataStream_5], fields=[f0]) -> SinkConversionToRow -> Sink: Select table sink (1/1) (0d3cd78d35480c44f09603786bf775e7) switched from DEPLOYING to RUNNING.
```

but no record is received or sent out.

See the image for the `DataStream` job
[image]

and see the image for the `TableAPI` job
[image]

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.
Kind regards!

Comment: The answer with an example is in this Stack Overflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62725535/using-python-user-defined-function-in-a-java-flink-job/64343258#64343258

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write one job that starts and ends with the DataStream API, and uses the Table API in the middle, then here's a simple example you can build upon.

Note that the details involved have changed some from release to release, and this particular example works as written with Flink 1.11. [FLIP-136: Improve interoperability between DataStream and Table API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-136%3A++Improve+interoperability+between+DataStream+and+Table+API) is being worked on to make this even easier.

```java
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.SingleOutputStreamOperator;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.Table;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.java.StreamTableEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.types.Row;

import static org.apache.flink.table.api.Expressions.$;

public class BackAndForth {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Long>> rawInput = env.fromElements(
                new Tuple2<>("u2", 0L),
                new Tuple2<>("u1", 5L),
                new Tuple2<>("u2", 1L),
                new Tuple2<>("u3", 1L),
                new Tuple2<>("u1", 0L),
                new Tuple2<>("u1", 3L),
                new Tuple2<>("u2", 2L));

        Table events = tableEnv.fromDataStream(rawInput, $("userId"), $("value"));

        Table results = events
                .select($("userId"), $("value"))
                .where($("value").isGreater(0));

        tableEnv
                .toAppendStream(results, Row.class)
                .print();

        env.execute();
    }
}
```

You may be concerned that in the web UI it is showing "Records Sent: 0" and "Records Received: 0". This is very misleading. These Flink metrics only measure records and bytes flowing within Flink, and do not report any i/o with external systems. These metrics also do not report records and bytes flowing between operators that are chained together. Everything in those two jobs is chained, so records/bytes sent/received will always be zero in this case.